# BroadCastReceiver to listen incoming call and work between time interval

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

*I want to develope a receiver class which will listen Phone state. And I want to work on doSomething() using incoming phone number.*

*And my need is that my receiver should work between some time interval (like 12:30PM to 01:00PM), other than this time interval my receiver should not work.*

**What I did yet :**

*This is my BroadcastReceiver class :*

```
public class MyTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    protected AudioManager audioManager;// = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    protected Context context;
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      this.context = context;
      String action = intent.getAction();
             if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
              if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                                  TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                  //Incoming call 
               doSomething(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
              }         
             }
             else {

             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
             Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
             SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[0]);
             if(!message.isEmail())
                 doSomething(message.getOriginatingAddress());

             }

     }
}
```

*And I am using it as in my activity :*

```
registerReceiver(new MyTest(), new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
```

*In manifest I declaired it as*

```
<receiver android:name=".MyTest"></receiver>
```

**Problem :**

Its working if my application is running on foreground, but when I closes my application its not working. 
*I didn't write any code on onPause() or other methods of Activity life cycle.*

***What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to this?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your receiver in your manifest file like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: with manifest you can't but you can put check in your onReceive method to execute your task as per your condition.......

Comment: and if i don't want to call the receiver for outgoing calls, then is there a specific intent for that ?